# Weird page breaking in letter style after closing

Tags: page-breaking, letters

I want to add text to a letter after the signature.  This is a sort of appendix.  However, the page breaking after the closing is very strange.  If I include a LaTeX list in one of the paragraphs after the signature, I get page breaks, but only on paragraph boundaries, so that I sometimes have a great deal of whitespace at the bottom of a page.  If I don't include an `enumerate` list, then there is no page breaking at all after the closing; the text simply runs down to the bottom of the page, and there are no subsequent pages.

A solution is to simply avoid using `\closing{}`, and construct the signature element by hand using e.g. `\hspace` and `\vspace`.  I'm wondering whether there's a more elegant approach.

Given the nature of the problem, the MWE below isn't very minimal; it has to include a lot of text.  Delete the `enumerate` list to see the second kind of behavior.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}
\address{Lorem\\ ipsum\\ dolor\\ sit\\ amet\\ elit}
\signature{Lucretius}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Lorem\\ dolor\\ elit\\ lectus}
\opening{Dear Epicurus:}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In in
pretium lectus. Ut mauris metus, consectetur vitae congue sed,
varius et quam. Mauris eleifend efficitur nunc, sed lacinia purus
pharetra non. Quisque eleifend odio rhoncus nibh volutpat, ac
iaculis risus sagittis. 

\closing{Best regards,}

Pellentesque sed faucibus quam. Aenean euismod vulputate tellus,
sed hendrerit purus aliquam in. Phasellus dapibus suscipit arcu,
sed lacinia augue elementum ut. Vivamus dignissim justo libero,
at blandit sem bibendum vel. Nullam luctus nec eros vitae luctus.
Maecenas porttitor ipsum et massa volutpat rhoncus. Donec sit
amet tortor varius, interdum mauris vel, malesuada velit. Nullam
eu sapien viverra, imperdiet magna in, dapibus arcu. Cras
pulvinar sed lorem id posuere. Curabitur maximus leo ut venenatis
varius. 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Nullam 
\item dictum 
\item sagittis 
\end{enumerate}
Nullam dictum sagittis pellentesque. Nunc at ultrices
tortor. Quisque sit amet lobortis lectus. Quisque vel vulputate
quam, ut scelerisque dolor. Etiam sollicitudin nisi vitae augue
interdum, eget condimentum est lobortis. Donec nec erat viverra,
mollis nisl nec, feugiat massa. 

Phasellus consectetur tortor ac
euismod lobortis. Ut aliquet venenatis dolor vitae tempor.
Aliquam non fermentum nibh, volutpat sodales ipsum. Fusce rhoncus
tempus fringilla. In faucibus efficitur velit id aliquam. Proin
quis lorem ex. Maecenas tempus, turpis at sollicitudin
ullamcorper, risus neque convallis metus, in tempor urna lorem id
magna. Suspendisse justo felis, porta nec justo eu, pellentesque
cursus nulla. 

Pellentesque sed faucibus quam. Aenean euismod vulputate tellus,
sed hendrerit purus aliquam in. Phasellus dapibus suscipit arcu,
sed lacinia augue elementum ut. Vivamus dignissim justo libero,
at blandit sem bibendum vel. Nullam luctus nec eros vitae luctus.
Maecenas porttitor ipsum et massa volutpat rhoncus. Donec sit
amet tortor varius, interdum mauris vel, malesuada velit. Nullam
eu sapien viverra, imperdiet magna in, dapibus arcu. Cras
pulvinar sed lorem id posuere. Curabitur maximus leo ut venenatis
varius. Nullam dictum sagittis pellentesque. Nunc at ultrices
tortor. Quisque sit amet lobortis lectus. Quisque vel vulputate
quam, ut scelerisque dolor. Etiam sollicitudin nisi vitae augue
interdum, eget condimentum est lobortis. Donec nec erat viverra,
mollis nisl nec, feugiat massa. Phasellus consectetur tortor ac
euismod lobortis. Ut aliquet venenatis dolor vitae tempor.
Aliquam non fermentum nibh, volutpat sodales ipsum. Fusce rhoncus
tempus fringilla. In faucibus efficitur velit id aliquam. Proin
quis lorem ex. Maecenas tempus, turpis at sollicitudin
ullamcorper, risus neque convallis metus, in tempor urna lorem id
magna. Suspendisse justo felis, porta nec justo eu, pellentesque
cursus nulla. Nullam mi dolor, lacinia a sem et, auctor interdum
odio. Nam quis blandit velit, vitae molestie enim. Ut sem mauris,
malesuada varius sodales a, mollis a lorem. Praesent viverra,
nulla sed dignissim hendrerit, felis enim vulputate mauris, at
ullamcorper urna metus vitae leo. In nec suscipit ipsum.
Pellentesque placerat gravida nibh, sed fringilla lacus dignissim
sed. Ut iaculis enim sapien, et lacinia lectus maximus vitae.
Nunc viverra pulvinar sem, non porttitor lectus cursus id. Duis
ex urna, porta sit amet sem nec, euismod eleifend erat. Praesent
ut eleifend felis, in tincidunt ligula. Vestibulum porta vehicula
rhoncus. Etiam a aliquet nisl, ut maximus quam. Quisque a nunc ac
arcu pharetra blandit id quis neque. Phasellus pellentesque
ultricies sapien.

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I would avoid the `letter` class. It's not necessary, for *most* applications. You can get by without it and replace it with a regular `article` document class. Here is one such implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1.5in}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indent
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
  Lorem \\ ipsum \\ dolor \\ sit \\ amet \\ elit \\[1.5\normalbaselineskip]
  \today
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  Lorem \\ dolor \\ elit \\ lectus
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip

Dear Epicurus:

\medskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In in
pretium lectus. Ut mauris metus, consectetur vitae congue sed,
varius et quam. Mauris eleifend efficitur nunc, sed lacinia purus
pharetra non. Quisque eleifend odio rhoncus nibh volutpat, ac
iaculis risus sagittis. 

\medskip

\hspace{.5\textwidth}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  Best regards, \\[4\normalbaselineskip]
  Lucretius
\end{tabular}

\medskip

Pellentesque sed faucibus quam. Aenean euismod vulputate tellus,
sed hendrerit purus aliquam in. Phasellus dapibus suscipit arcu,
sed lacinia augue elementum ut. Vivamus dignissim justo libero,
at blandit sem bibendum vel. Nullam luctus nec eros vitae luctus.
Maecenas porttitor ipsum et massa volutpat rhoncus. Donec sit
amet tortor varius, interdum mauris vel, malesuada velit. Nullam
eu sapien viverra, imperdiet magna in, dapibus arcu. Cras
pulvinar sed lorem id posuere. Curabitur maximus leo ut venenatis
varius. 
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Nullam 
  \item dictum 
  \item sagittis 
\end{enumerate}
Nullam dictum sagittis pellentesque. Nunc at ultrices
tortor. Quisque sit amet lobortis lectus. Quisque vel vulputate
quam, ut scelerisque dolor. Etiam sollicitudin nisi vitae augue
interdum, eget condimentum est lobortis. Donec nec erat viverra,
mollis nisl nec, feugiat massa. 

Phasellus consectetur tortor ac
euismod lobortis. Ut aliquet venenatis dolor vitae tempor.
Aliquam non fermentum nibh, volutpat sodales ipsum. Fusce rhoncus
tempus fringilla. In faucibus efficitur velit id aliquam. Proin
quis lorem ex. Maecenas tempus, turpis at sollicitudin
ullamcorper, risus neque convallis metus, in tempor urna lorem id
magna. Suspendisse justo felis, porta nec justo eu, pellentesque
cursus nulla. 

Pellentesque sed faucibus quam. Aenean euismod vulputate tellus,
sed hendrerit purus aliquam in. Phasellus dapibus suscipit arcu,
sed lacinia augue elementum ut. Vivamus dignissim justo libero,
at blandit sem bibendum vel. Nullam luctus nec eros vitae luctus.
Maecenas porttitor ipsum et massa volutpat rhoncus. Donec sit
amet tortor varius, interdum mauris vel, malesuada velit. Nullam
eu sapien viverra, imperdiet magna in, dapibus arcu. Cras
pulvinar sed lorem id posuere. Curabitur maximus leo ut venenatis
varius. Nullam dictum sagittis pellentesque. Nunc at ultrices
tortor. Quisque sit amet lobortis lectus. Quisque vel vulputate
quam, ut scelerisque dolor. Etiam sollicitudin nisi vitae augue
interdum, eget condimentum est lobortis. Donec nec erat viverra,
mollis nisl nec, feugiat massa. Phasellus consectetur tortor ac
euismod lobortis. Ut aliquet venenatis dolor vitae tempor.
Aliquam non fermentum nibh, volutpat sodales ipsum. Fusce rhoncus
tempus fringilla. In faucibus efficitur velit id aliquam. Proin
quis lorem ex. Maecenas tempus, turpis at sollicitudin
ullamcorper, risus neque convallis metus, in tempor urna lorem id
magna. Suspendisse justo felis, porta nec justo eu, pellentesque
cursus nulla. Nullam mi dolor, lacinia a sem et, auctor interdum
odio. Nam quis blandit velit, vitae molestie enim. Ut sem mauris,
malesuada varius sodales a, mollis a lorem. Praesent viverra,
nulla sed dignissim hendrerit, felis enim vulputate mauris, at
ullamcorper urna metus vitae leo. In nec suscipit ipsum.
Pellentesque placerat gravida nibh, sed fringilla lacus dignissim
sed. Ut iaculis enim sapien, et lacinia lectus maximus vitae.
Nunc viverra pulvinar sem, non porttitor lectus cursus id. Duis
ex urna, porta sit amet sem nec, euismod eleifend erat. Praesent
ut eleifend felis, in tincidunt ligula. Vestibulum porta vehicula
rhoncus. Etiam a aliquet nisl, ut maximus quam. Quisque a nunc ac
arcu pharetra blandit id quis neque. Phasellus pellentesque
ultricies sapien.

\end{document}
```

It's straight-forward and hassle-free. Document layout matches the flow without textual/content specifications in the preamble suddenly causing problems later in the document.

Answer (score 2):

`\closing` does two things that affect the following text in this case, firstly it adds `6\baselineskip`  of white space before the signature line (for you to sign by hand, presumably) in this case this happens to make page breaking mid-paragraph in the following text unlikely, just as it happens to fall, so in the example below I shortened the paragraph to better demonstrate the main problem which is:

The main thing affecting you though is that the definition of `\closing` starts with `\stopbreaks` this is documented (in letter.dtx) as

> \begin{macro}{\stopbreaks}
>
> ```
> When the command |\stopbreaks| is issued no page breaks should
> occur until |\startbreaks| is called.
> ```

which is a bit of a clue that putting `\startbreaks` after `\closing will do what you want.

First page by default:

[image]

add `\startbreaks`

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}
\address{Lorem\\ ipsum\\ dolor\\ sit\\ amet\\ elit}
\signature{Lucretius}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Lorem\\ dolor\\ elit\\ lectus}
\opening{Dear Epicurus:}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In in
pretium lectus. Ut mauris metus, consectetur vitae congue sed,
varius et quam. Mauris eleifend efficitur nunc, sed lacinia purus
pharetra non. Quisque eleifend odio rhoncus nibh volutpat, ac
iaculis risus sagittis. 

\closing{Best regards,}

\startbreaks

Pellentesque sed faucibus quam. Aenean euismod vulputate tellus,
sed hendrerit purus aliquam in. Phasellus dapibus suscipit arcu,
sed lacinia augue elementum ut. Vivamus dignissim justo libero,
at blandit sem bibendum vel. Nullam luctus nec eros vitae luctus.
%Maecenas porttitor ipsum et massa volutpat rhoncus. Donec sit
%amet tortor varius, interdum mauris vel, malesuada velit. Nullam
%eu sapien viverra, imperdiet magna in, dapibus arcu. Cras
%pulvinar sed lorem id posuere. Curabitur maximus leo ut venenatis
%varius. 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Nullam 
\item dictum 
\item sagittis 
\end{enumerate}
Nullam dictum sagittis pellentesque. Nunc at ultrices
tortor. Quisque sit amet lobortis lectus. Quisque vel vulputate
quam, ut scelerisque dolor. Etiam sollicitudin nisi vitae augue
interdum, eget condimentum est lobortis. Donec nec erat viverra,
mollis nisl nec, feugiat massa. 

Phasellus consectetur tortor ac
euismod lobortis. Ut aliquet venenatis dolor vitae tempor.
Aliquam non fermentum nibh, volutpat sodales ipsum. Fusce rhoncus
tempus fringilla. In faucibus efficitur velit id aliquam. Proin
quis lorem ex. Maecenas tempus, turpis at sollicitudin
ullamcorper, risus neque convallis metus, in tempor urna lorem id
magna. Suspendisse justo felis, porta nec justo eu, pellentesque
cursus nulla. 

Pellentesque sed faucibus quam. Aenean euismod vulputate tellus,
sed hendrerit purus aliquam in. Phasellus dapibus suscipit arcu,
sed lacinia augue elementum ut. Vivamus dignissim justo libero,
at blandit sem bibendum vel. Nullam luctus nec eros vitae luctus.
Maecenas porttitor ipsum et massa volutpat rhoncus. Donec sit
amet tortor varius, interdum mauris vel, malesuada velit. Nullam
eu sapien viverra, imperdiet magna in, dapibus arcu. Cras
pulvinar sed lorem id posuere. Curabitur maximus leo ut venenatis
varius. Nullam dictum sagittis pellentesque. Nunc at ultrices
tortor. Quisque sit amet lobortis lectus. Quisque vel vulputate
quam, ut scelerisque dolor. Etiam sollicitudin nisi vitae augue
interdum, eget condimentum est lobortis. Donec nec erat viverra,
mollis nisl nec, feugiat massa. Phasellus consectetur tortor ac
euismod lobortis. Ut aliquet venenatis dolor vitae tempor.
Aliquam non fermentum nibh, volutpat sodales ipsum. Fusce rhoncus
tempus fringilla. In faucibus efficitur velit id aliquam. Proin
quis lorem ex. Maecenas tempus, turpis at sollicitudin
ullamcorper, risus neque convallis metus, in tempor urna lorem id
magna. Suspendisse justo felis, porta nec justo eu, pellentesque
cursus nulla. Nullam mi dolor, lacinia a sem et, auctor interdum
odio. Nam quis blandit velit, vitae molestie enim. Ut sem mauris,
malesuada varius sodales a, mollis a lorem. Praesent viverra,
nulla sed dignissim hendrerit, felis enim vulputate mauris, at
ullamcorper urna metus vitae leo. In nec suscipit ipsum.
Pellentesque placerat gravida nibh, sed fringilla lacus dignissim
sed. Ut iaculis enim sapien, et lacinia lectus maximus vitae.
Nunc viverra pulvinar sem, non porttitor lectus cursus id. Duis
ex urna, porta sit amet sem nec, euismod eleifend erat. Praesent
ut eleifend felis, in tincidunt ligula. Vestibulum porta vehicula
rhoncus. Etiam a aliquet nisl, ut maximus quam. Quisque a nunc ac
arcu pharetra blandit id quis neque. Phasellus pellentesque
ultricies sapien.

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```